# Asking about guidelines on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Is it OK to ask on Stack Overflow about good/bad practices concerning modal windows?

The question is:

> There is a Delphi 6 application made years ago and it uses modal windows to output goods' references. Its behavior is very convenient to me, especially the fact that these windows are modal, except one thing: I would like to go from reference (all purchases of the goods) to actual purchase (non-modal parent window). Is it ok to do so from a modal window? How to do it the best way?

I put it to programmers.stackexchange.com but do not know whether it is the right place.

Comment: If stripped from its Delphi context, this *could* be on topic on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean *"is it ok"*; from whose (or what's) perspective? How would you define *"the best way"*?

Answer (score 7):

Nope. It's textbook subjective and too broad.

There's plenty of good stuff out there already, though: Google e.g. `modal windows pros and cons` or `modal windows best practices`.

Comment: I do not need ALL the pros and cons. I need to ask about specific problem, but it is conceptual. I would like to do this on some of StackExchange sites.

Comment: @Paul could you maybe put that question in this question?

Answer (score 1):

No, It is generally not ok to ask about choices you can make.

The way question is phrased now makes it awful fit for any SE site. "The best way" is almost always too-broad or opinion-based. At very least such question must include solid definition of "better" to be answerable.

Note that many of "the best way" questions are performance related (speed of code, size/readability, user performance like in this case) and should include results of measurements you did for options or at least the current numbers with the goal.

As suggested in comments https://ux.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit for the question after adding details (assuming you are looking for user interaction behavior, not coding practice).